# Can Graphhopper Matrix API be used offline? (Embedded mode)

Tags: graphhopper

I'd like to use the [Graphhopper Matrix API](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/matrix/) offline similar how I can use the Graphopper Directions API offline. Is this possible? Or is the Matrix API only accessible through HTTP request?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to host the *Matrix Api* binaries locally? Can i access the binaries anywhere? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question belongs to SO ... it can be used offline either via Java or http, comes with documentation, with proper Maven integration etc, but [it is not open source](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/131#issuecomment-60588289). See [this comparison](https://graphhopper.com/#open-source-comparison).

Comment: I understand that they are keeping it closed source but is it possible to actually use the _Matrix API_ offline? I only see documentation for making HTTP requests to it.

Comment: As it is said in the answer: yes it is possible via Java or http

Comment: Karussell, I appreciate you trying to help but could you point me to a description of how to use this API offline? All I can see is a Java client which still hits the GraphHopper server to get the results.

Comment: As this is a closed source product you'll get documentation when you buy it.